# Regarding deleting a node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Following code doesn't compiles (code is partial/modified code, for obvious reasons)

```
    typedef struct l_list{
           int value;
           struct l_list *next;
    }list; // given

    void delete(list **head, int value){ //given
         ...         
         free(current); // segmentation fault
         ...
     }

    int main() /// given for testcase
    {  
               list listg[2];

              // initialized 2 struct  and link them with each other using next pointer one after another (think like arrayed linked list)

               delete(&listg, 3);
    }
```

> `error: cannot convert list (*)[2] {aka l_list (*)[2]} to list** {aka l_list**} for argument 1 to void delete(list**, int)`

Ques1: compile help. Please advise!

Ques2: If we have to implement delete as above, in function how to free a pointer within an array list? (How to remove the segmentation fault?)

Comment: For Q1: change `list listg[5];` to `list *listg;`.

Comment: A pointer to a pointer to something is *not* the same as a pointer to an array of something. There are many duplicates of this if you just search a little.

Comment: @herohuyongtao This is what I did to compile, I list *listg = malloc(sizeof(list) * 5);

Comment: Completely unrelated, but you should never have global names with leading underscores, those are reserved by the C standard specification.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Please do not make a issue of underscores, it is just a partial code. (but yes actual code had underscores)

Comment: But it *is* an issue, just unrelated to the problem your having. If the C standard specification says (and I only paraphrase) "Names with leading underscores are not to be used", and you have names with leading underscores, then technically your program is not a valid C program.

Comment: Q2: There is no need for `free` because it is not secured by `malloc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What if I change the code to-> list listg* = malloc(sizeof(list) * 5); // segmentation fault exists when you free

Comment: It is not possible to pass the `free` is not the address of the first if it is ensured so. 
`free` is can individually is a case where it is secured separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that `listg` is an **array of `list`**.
Then, `&listg` is a **pointer to an array of `list`**.

`delete()` expects **pointer to a pointer to `list`** in the first parameter. So, you have a type mismatch, and thus the compiler error. This can be corrected by actually passing in the address of a pointer to `list`.

```
list listg[5] = {
    { 1, &listg[1] },
    { 2, &listg[2] },
    { 3, &listg[3] },
    { 4, &listg[4] },
    { 5, 0 } };
list *listp = listg;
delete(&listp, 3);
```

You are not allowed to call `free()` on a pointer value that was not returned by `malloc()` (or one of its siblings). This means you cannot call `free()` on automatic nor static memory nor on an address in the middle of a dynamic allocation. However, you can remove the node associated with `3` from the list.

Node removal is normally achieved by manipulating the `next` pointer of the node that precedes the node you want to remove away from its current value and toward the node that follows the node you want to remove. You will need code (likely some kind of loop) to identify the node you want to remove and the preceding node to accomplish this. If you need to remove the first element of the list, this is done by changing the head of the list to be the next item in the list instead.

Comment: I know how to implement the delete. But in a normal delete you link previous->next = current->next; // where current is found node and then you free the current. But freeing current here gives a segmentation fault

Comment: listg[5] = malloc(sizeof(list) * 5) // still segmentation fault persists

Comment: Sorry, making so many mistakes. list listg* = malloc(sizeof(list) * 5); // segmentation fault exists when you free

Comment: I made the explanation of `free()`s restriction more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
list listg[5];
```

is not a list of 5 nodes strung together by their `next` pointers. It's an array of five lists. (And "list" is a very misleading name for that struct-- "node" would be better.) I don't know what you expected `delete` to do to it (since you haven't shown us `delete()`), but the signature of that function doesn't match what you gave it.

And I have no idea what you mean by "array list". Do you mean an array of lists? And does "a pointer within an array list" mean a pointer to an element of such an array? And what does it mean to free such a pointer?

Comment: Yes, array of nodes, linked to each other. When you delete an node in such an array linked list, how will you free that unlinked node?

Comment: I had to implement the delete, so used a standard delete for a linked list.

Comment: @codeymodey Since you have an array of "nodes", you *can't* free them one by one. They will be automatically free'd when the array goes out of scope. What you should do is only *unlink* the node from the list.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For Q1: change list listg[5]; to list *listg; is that correct?

Comment: @codeymodey: I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but you seem to have a deep misunderstanding of what a linked list is. The nodes in this array are *not* linked together by their `next` pointers; you could have linked them, but you didn't. Their `next` pointers are uninitialized and point somewhere-or-other, maybe to valid memory addresses (containing who knows what), maybe not. The phrase "array linked list" makes no sense. You must go back and consult the textbook. You might also verify that "free" means what you think it does.

Comment: @Beta You don't need to be sorry to tell me any thing, I need to learn a lot. My apologies for giving an incomplete question, that was the trick in the question(i thought it is understood). Yes, the nodes are linked, imagine an array with struct nodes linked consecutively. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @codeymodey: Yes, it makes sense. I suggest you concentrate on getting your code to compile; post a complete example of what *does* compile, and tell us what feature you're having trouble adding.

Comment: @Beta see the question again, I need to get over with segmentation fault

Comment: @codeymodey: you're still editing the question, and the code still isn't complete. I'm not going to guess which missing pieces are really missing and which you simply omitted in the post.

Comment: @Beta it is complete now, please include header yourself

Answer (score 0):

fix sample(array version)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct l_list{
    int value;
    struct l_list *next;
}list;

void delete(list **head, int value){
    list *current, *previous = NULL;

    for (current = *head; current != NULL; previous = current, current = current->next){
        if (current->value == value){
            break;
        }
    }

    if (current != NULL){
        if (previous == NULL){
            *head = current->next;
        } else{
            previous->next = current->next;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void print(list *head){
    while(head){
        printf("%d ", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() { 
    list listg[5];
    listg[0].value = 1;
    listg[0].next = listg + 1;
    listg[1].value = 3;
    listg[1].next = NULL;

    list *head = &listg[0];
    print(head);
    delete(&head, 3);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```